# How do i make the background scroll slower than the foreground a.k.a parallax scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to use pure css because js lags in chrome. I want the background image to scroll slower than the foreground (the white box below). This is my code -

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}


.parallax .bg__foo {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/30354/parallax1.jpg);
}

#box1 {
  background-color:white;
  width:100%;
  height:500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parallax">    
<div class="bg__foo"></div>    
<div id="box1"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use *skrollr js*. Refer the plugin doc here - https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr

Comment: CSS only solution here: http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/